# Angular-UI ui-keypress not working

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, angularjs, angular-ui

I'm having trouble getting even a simple use of angular-ui up and running. I want to be able to easily detect keypresses, for instance, to automatically add an item after pressing `enter` in a text box without having to press an Add button.

---

Here's my current attempt:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>Main</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet", href="http://angular-ui.github.com/angular-ui/build/angular-ui.css" />
</head>
<body ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <button ng-click="add()">Add</button>
  <input type="text" ui-keypress="{enter: 'add()'}" />
  {{item}}
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js">    </script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://angular-ui.github.com/angular-ui/build/angular-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.directives']);
```

---

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.item = "";

  $scope.add = function () {
    $scope.item = "Item Added";
  }
}
```

You can see the behavior here: http://jsfiddle.net/NbjZL/5/. Note that clicking the button after typing text works, but pressing `enter` after typing text does not. I've read what documentation I can find and have looked at several examples, but I'm sure I'm still missing some small thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Angular ui was not able to find the angular app. All you need to do is to specify the app name in ng-app to get it working.

```
<html ng-app="myModule" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Check the [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jayrmotta/NbjZL/70/) to see the code work

Comment: Ugh! I knew not knowing that that little attribute actually did was going to bite me eventually. Many kudos to you sir!